# Get json variable by searching by another variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have some json data like this:

```
{
"views": [{
    "url": "\/en",
    "viewname": "Home",
    "pagetitle": "My wonderful home page",
    "description": "This is the home page of a wonderful site"
}, {
    "url": "\/en\/about",
    "viewname": "About",
    "pagetitle": "About this wonderful site",
    "description": "All about this wonderful site"
}]
}
```

I load this data using an ajax call like this:

```
var url = '/sitemap';
views = $.getJSON(url);
```

What I would like to do is this:
**What is the value of pagetitle where viewname = 'Home'?**

I am using jquery - but pure javascript is great as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your logic in the success callback of `$.getJSON` so that the search take place inside the array of objects in `views` array of the JSON result. Since, `views` is a array of objects, you can use `find()` operation on the `viewname` property to match its value with `Home`. `({viewname})` refers to the destructuring way to getting only the value of `viewname` property rather than the entire property.

```
var url = '/sitemap';
$.getJSON(url, function(result){
    var arr = result.views;
    var findObj = arr.find(({viewname}) => 'Home');
    if(findObj){
      //here is your pagetitle
      console.log(findObj.pagetitle);
    }

});
```

Comment: missing the value comparison in find

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do that with pure javascript :

```
 const myItem = views.find((el) => {
      return el.viewname === 'Home';
});

console.log(myItem.pagetitle)
```

This will return the first element with viewname === 'Home'

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```js
var arr = [{
  "url": "\ / en ",
  "viewname": "Home",
  "pagetitle": "My wonderful home page",
  "description": "This is the home page of a wonderful site"
}, {
  "url": "\/en\/about",
  "viewname": "About",
  "pagetitle": "About this wonderful site",
  "description": "All about this wonderful site"
}]



var viewname = 'Home';
var pagetitle = arr.find(o => o.viewname === viewname).pagetitle;
console.log(pagetitle);
```

Answer (score 0):

Out of memory:

`views.views[0].viewname == 'home'`

then

`views.views[0].pagetitle== 'My wonderful home page'`

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```js
var obj = {
"views": [{
    "url": "\/en",
    "viewname": "Home",
    "pagetitle": "My wonderful home page",
    "description": "This is the home page of a wonderful site"
}, {
    "url": "\/en\/about",
    "viewname": "About",
    "pagetitle": "About this wonderful site",
    "description": "All about this wonderful site"
}]
};

var viewName = 'Home';
var selectedObj = obj.views.find(item => item.viewname === viewName);
console.log(selectedObj.pagetitle);
```